# JS seperate string by command and any number

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to seperate a string.

```
"5 tablespoons unsalted butter, melted and cooled, 1 tablespoon, softened, for brushing muffin cups, 2 cups cornmeal"
```

I want to get:

```
5 tablespoons unsalted butter, melted and cooled
1 tablespoon, softened, for brushing muffin cups
2 cups cornmeal
```

The pattern is: `, <any number>`
I did some search online and tried `.split(/(, \d+)/)`. But, it doesn't work as it give me five results. Can i get some help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `(, \d+)` pattern is wrapped with a capturing group and that is why split method returns both matches (comma + space + 1+ digits) and non-matches (the rest).

You may use

```js
var s = "5 tablespoons unsalted butter, melted and cooled, 1 tablespoon, softened, for brushing muffin cups, 2 cups cornmeal";
console.log(s.split(/,\s*(?=\d+\b)/));
```

The `/,\s*(?=\d+\b)/` regex matches

- `,` - a comma
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(?=\d+\b)` - followed with 1+ digits and a word boundary.

Comment: Thanks! Can I ask another question? I want to seperate the string by third appearance of period  `.` I tried `str.split((/\. {3}/))`, but it doesn't work. Can I get some help? Thanks

Comment: @kevinzf It is a different question, but I think something like `s.match(/(?:[^.]*\.){1,3}/g)`,  `s.match(/[^.\s](?:[^.]*\.){1,2}[^.]*/g)` or `s.match(/(?:[^.]*\.){1,2}[^.]*/g)` will work for you. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ip1Kw6/1).

Comment: Thanks! When i trying to use split, I got three empty string. `"sentence1. sentence2. sentence3. sentence4. sentence5. sentence6. ".split(/(?:[^.]*\.){1,3}/g)`. Do I need to change anything? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this could be improved, but maybe try this:

```js
const str = "5 tablespoons unsalted butter, melted and cooled, 1 tablespoon, softened, for brushing muffin cups, 2 cups cornmeal"
const result = str.split(/(, \d.*),/).map(x => x.trim()).map(x => x.replace(/,\s/, ''))
```

The resulting array in `result` is what you're asking for.